# Using struct.pack to get total size of file and send it to server via TCP socket

Tags: python, struct, tcp

I'm trying to get total size of folder with all subfolders and files using following code:

```
def getTotalSize(self, filename):
    try:
        total = 0
        start_path = filename
        for path, dirs, files in os.walk(start_path):
            for f in files:
                fp = os.path.join(path, f)
                total += os.path.getsize(fp)
        totalInBytes = struct.pack('<I', total)
        self.s.sendall(totalInBytes)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

It works perfectly until I'm trying to get the size of the folder, that is 1 GB+ big, then it will send this error: `argument out of range`. I checked this [website](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html), but I can't find anything similar to this problem. What am I doing wrong? Is using struct for this kinda stuff even viable? Thanks for any tips!

**TRACEBACK**:

```
File "rshell_client.py", line 163, in getTotalSize
totalInBytes = struct.pack('<I', total)
struct.error: argument out of range
```

Comment: Please post the actual traceback, not just a part of the error message. How big is "1 GB+"? ``<I`` should be enough to store a number representing 1 byte less than 4 GiB.

Comment: Well, there is no traceback, because the script will throw exception - `argument out of range` and go back to while loop. But the problem is actually with struct, it looks like it can't handle that much data. Script will always end before `totalInBytes = struct.pack('<I', total)`, when I'm trying to get the size of the folder with 9 GB, but even if I'm trying to get the size of one file that is exactly 1,7 GB big, it will throw the same exception.

Comment: Please remove the exception handler (which swallows the exception details and traceback) or call ``traceback.print_exc()`` when surpassing the error. Provide the ``total`` for which the error occurs as well.

Comment: Okay, traceback call is in actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format code `I` means a 4-byte unsigned int, [as seen in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html#format-characters).  4 bytes == 32 bits, 2^32 == 4294967296 possible values.  So values over the maximum of 2^32-1 can't be stored in an unsigned int.  If it MUST be an unsigned int and transmitted in bytes, then it's not possible.  Otherwise use a larger integer type.

Comment: Well, that fixed one problem, thanks. I will need to split the data because I'm using buffer based on file size. Now I see that it's not that practical. Thanks.